# How do I make reorder control of UITableViewCell in left side?

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-controls

I am doing a news reader app and I want to make it so that the user can choose show/hide news categories (such as top news, business, technology, sports, etc) and reorder them like the BBC news app in Android.

See the picture below:

[image]

My question is:

- How do I make reorder control in left side of cell?
  (Its default position is in the right side of the cell in edit mode)
- I have a checkbox custom control. How do I put it in right side of the cell?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Answer [If you're not using any accessories (detail disclosure, &c)]

(0) I assume you have your tables set up, &c.

(1) This solution only works if your tables cells are always draggable. Add this in your viewDidLoad to your Table View Controller .m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setEditing:YES];
}
```

(2) To make it so you can reorder your cells, add `cell.showsReorderControl = YES;` to your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

(3) Ensure that you have the tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: methods.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES; 
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
```

(4) Because you want the reorder control on the left, we have to take away the Delete circle usually there and the tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: method does that.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

(5) Last step, where the magic happens - add the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method, search for the cell's subviews, narrow it down to the private UITableViewCellReorderControl, and finally override it.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
            // Creates a new subview the size of the entire cell
            UIView *movedReorderControl = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))];
            // Adds the reorder control view to our new subview
            [movedReorderControl addSubview:view];
            // Adds our new subview to the cell
            [cell addSubview:movedReorderControl];
            // CGStuff to move it to the left
            CGSize moveLeft = CGSizeMake(movedReorderControl.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width, movedReorderControl.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height);
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -moveLeft.width, -moveLeft.height);
            // Performs the transform
            [movedReorderControl setTransform:transform];
        }
    }
}
```

I spent nearly ten hours trying to figure out a solution for when accessories and I couldn't do it. I need more experience and knowledge first. Simply doing the same thing to the reorder control on the disclosure button didn't work. So I hope this would works for now; and if I figure it out in the future I'll be sure to update this.

> Hi Hoang Van Ha, this is my first answer ever, and I only started learning Objective-C a month ago, so I'm still quite a noob.
>
> I've been trying to do the same thing with my app and have been searching for hours how to do it. Apple's documentation isn't very much help when it comes to this. I found it quite frustrating when people would simply link to the documentation. I wanted to yell at them. I hope my answer helped you.
>
> Lots of kudos to [b2Cloud](http://b2cloud.com.au/about) because I used some of their code from [this article](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point) and adapted it for my answers.

Comment: fantastic Mr.Luke.... i need both delete control and reorder control on left side, is it possible?

Comment: Do you know how to make the entire cell the reorder control so you don't just have to grab the little icon?

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer. I've searched for this for a while now, and this worked beautifully. Thanks Luke.

Comment: I had a problem with this solution, the function willDisplayCell can get called multiple times for the same cell, for example when you scroll a cell out of the windows and then inside. 
When this happen and you call the transform again, the icon disappear to the left. They way I fix this is, instead of using transforms, I set the Y position of the new view to a fixed location:

CGRect newFrame = movedReorderControl.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = -220;
movedReorderControl.frame = newFrame;

Comment: I'll point out that the issue that that @David raises also causes multiple UIView's to be added to the cell. It happens every time the TableView is scrolled. This is a memory leak due to the creation of views that are no longer used but hang around anyway. I had already subclassed the cell so I added a property to track the created view and reuse it in willDisplayCell.

Comment: Please note that Apple may reject your app because of touching non public classes.

Answer (score 24):

Instead of hunting for `UITableViewCellReorderControl`, **which is non-public API and might change in the future**, I recommend using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` over the `UITableView` and implement your own reordering logic.

I solved the general case (responding to a long press on any part of the cell) in [`HPReorderTableView`](https://github.com/hpique/HPReorderTableView), a drop-in replacement of UITableView. It can be easily modified to respond to touches on specific parts of the cell, for example by implementing `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` of the `reorderGestureRecognizer` delegate.

Comment: Please note there's a reason this guy has 23.7k reputation. The other answers are botches and will return to bite you in the future. Also do remember there is a good reason why Apple publishes UI guidelines and try to stick to them - users expect this control on the right.

Comment: This is true. UITableView's edit behavior is not customizable and the reason is that it hasn't been historically and now they can't add it. Instead, they have the more generic UICollectionView which easily works as a stand-in for UITableView and allows you to customize its behavior.

Answer (score 20):

Now there is a much easier solution for iOS 9 and later

```
tableView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

---

**Edit**:

As [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793916/roland) mentioned you should notice that "if you align your cells' subviews via `leading` and `trailing` anchors instead of `left` and `right`, this setting will flip everything."

Comment: If you align your cells' subviews via `leading` and `trailing` anchors instead of `left` and `right`, this setting will flip everything.

Comment: it also adds some stupid space between movement control and the cells contents...

Comment: @Starwavedid have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Luke Dubert, have cool answer for iOS 7 it should be changed a little bit to:

```
UIView *cellSubview = cell.subviews[0];
    for(UIView* view in cellSubview.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested on iOS 12 using swift 4.2, and instead of using `view.self.description == "UITableViewCellReorderControl"`, use `view.self.description.contains("UITableViewCellReorderControl")`

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for view in cell.subviews {
        if view.self.description.contains("UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
            let movedReorderControl = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.maxX, height: view.frame.maxY))
            movedReorderControl.addSubview(view)
            cell.addSubview(movedReorderControl)
            let moveLeft = CGSize(width: movedReorderControl.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width, height: movedReorderControl.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height)
            var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -moveLeft.width, y: -moveLeft.height)
            movedReorderControl.transform = transform
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to adjust the location of the reorder control. No, I didn't want to move it all the way to the left, but I was able to use your code to accomplish what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Luke's solution, I've found a reliable and straight forward way to make this happen:

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // set the frames of the other subviews here if necessary, for example: 
    // self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);

    for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
        if ([[[view class] description] containsString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Simply create a custom UITableViewCell, override its subview and modify the position of each view will work nicely in all known scenarios.

Performing the UITableViewReorderControl customization under willDisplayCellAtIndexPath doesn't work 100%, the first reorder button won't position correctly occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

This solution didn't work for me in iOS7 so I have created a version for both, I hope this it usefull:

```
- (void)moveReorderControl:(UITableViewCell *)cell subviewCell:(UIView *)subviewCell
{
    if([[[subviewCell class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {
    static int TRANSLATION_REORDER_CONTROL_Y = -20;

        //Code to move the reorder control, you change change it for your code, this works for me
        UIView* resizedGripView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,    CGRectGetMaxX(subviewCell.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(subviewCell.frame))];
        [resizedGripView addSubview:subviewCell];
        [cell addSubview:resizedGripView];

        //  Original transform
        const CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(subviewCell.frame.size.width - cell.frame.size.width, TRANSLATION_REORDER_CONTROL_Y);
        //  Move custom view so the grip's top left aligns with the cell's top left

        [resizedGripView setTransform:transform];
   }
}

//This method is due to the move cells icons is on right by default, we need to move it.
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == MEETING_BLOCK_TABLE_TAG) {
        for(UIView* subviewCell in cell.subviews)
        {
            if ([ROCFunctions isIOS7]) {
                if([[[subviewCell class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"]) {
                    for(UIView* subSubviewCell in subviewCell.subviews) {
                        [self moveReorderControl:cell subviewCell:subSubviewCell];
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                [self moveReorderControl:cell subviewCell:subviewCell];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone above.Here is my solution. have tested on iOS7 and iOS9

```
@implementation StoryPreviewCell
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //subviews contains first level and second level views. 
    NSMutableArray *subviews = [NSMutableArray array];
    [subviews addObjectsFromArray:self.subviews];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<self.subviews.count; i++) {
        UIView *firstLevelView = self.subviews[i];
        if(firstLevelView.subviews.count) [subviews addObjectsFromArray:firstLevelView.subviews];
    }

    for(UIView* view in subviews) {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {
            UIView *reorderControl = view;
            CGFloat leftMoveDistance = 100;//can customize
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -leftMoveDistance, 0);
            reorderControl.transform = transform;
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Xamarin, here it is my solution based on @luke-dubert answer, but taking care of removing the additional added views when reusing:

On TableViewSource:

```
public override void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    (cell as GraphBarLineCell)?.SetEditionMode(tableView.Editing);
}
```

On cell:

```
private UIView _reorderControlContainer;

public void SetEditionMode(bool editing)
    {
        _title.Frame = editing ? TitleFrameForEditing : TitleFrame;

        if (editing)
        {
            var reorderControl = Subviews.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Class.Name.Equals("UITableViewCellReorderControl"));

            if (reorderControl != null)
            {
                _reorderControlContainer?.RemoveFromSuperview();

                // Creates a new subview the size of the entire cell
                _reorderControlContainer = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, reorderControl.Frame.GetMaxX(), reorderControl.Frame.GetMaxY()));

                // Adds the reorder control view to our new subview
                _reorderControlContainer.AddSubview(reorderControl);

                // Adds our new subview to the cell
                AddSubview(_reorderControlContainer);

                // CGStuff to move it to the left
                var moveLeft = new CGSize(_reorderControlContainer.Frame.Size.Width - reorderControl.Frame.Size.Width,
                    _reorderControlContainer.Frame.Size.Height - reorderControl.Frame.Size.Height);

                var transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity();
                transform = CGAffineTransform.Translate(transform, -moveLeft.Width, -moveLeft.Height);
                _reorderControlContainer.Transform = transform;

                // Align the icon with the title
                var icon = reorderControl.Subviews[0];
                icon.Frame = new CGRect(10, 25, icon.Frame.Width, icon.Frame.Height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found a far easier solution that requires no absolute manual positioning of anything, and even works with animated transitions from/to editing mode. Should work for both iOS6 and 7.

Define this category on UIView somewhere:

```
@interface UIView (ClassSearch)

- (instancetype)subviewOfClassMatching:(NSString*)partialName;

@end

@implementation UIView (ClassSearch)

-(instancetype)subviewOfClassMatching:(NSString *)partialName
{
    if ([[[self class] description] rangeOfString:partialName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        return self;
    }

    for (UIView* v in self.subviews) {
        id match = [v subviewOfClassMatching:partialName];
        if (match) {
            return match;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Then, in your UITableViewCell subclass, override willTransitionToState like so:

```
-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];

    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {
        UIView* reorderControl = [self subviewOfClassMatching:@"ReorderControl"];
        UIView* reorderContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
        reorderContainer.transform = t;
        [self addSubview:reorderContainer];
        [reorderContainer addSubview:reorderControl];
    }
}
```

Note that the cell needs to be configured to show only the reorder control, otherwise more work needs to be done.