# how to perform a custom move of UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit

I want to move cells just as these two methods do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath;
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Before I use these methods above to move cells (by user's touch action), tableView's setEditing:animated: must be called first.

But what I want is user long press then drag a cell to move it without entering editing style, and i hope these moving view won't appear in cells' right, like this:

[image]

Any suggestion? Special thx!

Comment: you can look at this post :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141947/how-to-make-reorder-control-of-uitableviewcell-in-left-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point

but it can't use long press gesture to begin draging

And we can use [FMMoveTableView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/fmmovetableview) to do this.