# how to do the cell editing in the table view without making any changes in the design of the cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I am keeping my `tableview` as editable to drag and drop cells. But when I am doing that the design of the `cell` is changing such that every element is become centered and there is a right disclosure button of three lines. I need to do this by keeping the same design of the cell.without having any disclosure button and keeping the cell layout same as it is in the case of noneditable table view.I am implemented the editing like this `[tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];` in the didload and implemented the delegates as

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    NSInteger sourceRow = sourceIndexPath.row;
    NSInteger destRow = destinationIndexPath.row;
    id object = [array objectAtIndex:sourceRow];

    [array removeObjectAtIndex:sourceRow];
    [array insertObject:object atIndex:destRow];

}
```

Can anybody help me in acheiving this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11211905/440060) might help

Comment: +1 for the right answer @MarOux

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

Add this method to your tableView delegate to prevent indentation:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return  NO;
}
```

Then in your UITableViewCell subclass set all reordering views' alpha to 0:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
  [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
  if (editing) {
    for (UIView * view in self.subviews) {
      NSLog(@"%@",view);
      if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) rangeOfString: @"Reorder"].location != NSNotFound) {
        for (UIView *sv in view.subviews) {
          sv.alpha = 0.0f;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that this is a hack and I'm not sure if apple would reject the app over this.

Answer (score 0):

You should return NO to this method of the tableViewDatasource:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: then i am not able to edit.i need to drag the cell as earlier .my pbm is i dont need to change the design for editing.then also didselect is not working