# Moving reordering control to left

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to move the reordering control to the left of the cell. I am using custom cells and my cell has button. I am actually able to move it the left by using the following function. But my right button is originally where the default reordering control is and hence is not accessible even after applying the transform. The part which is not behind is accessible.

As reference I have used these following links 
http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point

[How to make reorder control of UITableViewCell in left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141947/how-to-make-reorder-control-of-uitableviewcell-in-left-side)

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark rows reordering

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
            UIView* resizedGripView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), 48)];
            [resizedGripView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [resizedGripView addSubview:view];
            [cell addSubview:resizedGripView];

            //  Original transform

           const CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(40 - cell.frame.size.width, 1);


            [resizedGripView setTransform:transform];
            /*for(UIImageView* cellGrip in view.subviews)
            {
                if([cellGrip isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                    [cellGrip setImage:nil];
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Please see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBDLG.png

The edit button in the cell is not accessible on the original location of reorder control. Rest is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I hope it helps

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {

            UIView* resizedGripView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))];
            [resizedGripView addSubview:view];
            [cell addSubview:resizedGripView];

            //  Original transform
            const CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(view.frame.size.width - cell.frame.size.width, 1);
            //  Move custom view so the grip's top left aligns with the cell's top left

            [resizedGripView setTransform:transform];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works fine but it makes whole row draggle and buttons added in cell is not accessible any more.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 8.2.1,
Swift 3.x

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.subviews.forEach() {
        if ($0.description.range(of: "UITableViewCellReorderControl") != nil) {
            let resizedGripView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: $0.frame.maxX, height: $0.frame.maxY))
            resizedGripView.addSubview($0)
            cell.addSubview(resizedGripView)
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: $0.frame.size.width - cell.frame.size.width, y:  1)
            resizedGripView.transform = transform
        }
    }
}
```