# tableviewcell does not contains UITableViewCellReorderControl in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to relocate the reorder bar of a tableviewcell which appears at the right side of the row by default.So I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141947/how-to-make-reorder-control-of-uitableviewcell-in-left-side) But when I logs the sub views, the UITableViewCellReorderControl does not exists at all. But when I set:

```
[self setEditing:YES];
[tableView setEditing:YES];
```

if appears on the right side.

My approach so far:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    {
         NSLog(@"Tableview subviews: %@",[[subviewCell class] description]);
    }
}
```

AND

```
for(UIView* subviewCell in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
   NSLog(@"Tableview subviews: %@",[[subviewCell class] description]);
}
```

But the first one logs:

```
Tableview subviews: UITableViewCellContentView
Tableview subviews: _UITableViewCellSeparatorView
Tableview subviews: UITableViewCellContentView
Tableview subviews: _UITableViewCellSeparatorView
```

And the second code logs:

```
Tableview subviews: UIImageView
Tableview subviews: UIImageView
Tableview subviews: UIImageView
Tableview subviews: UITextField
Tableview subviews: UIImageView
Tableview subviews: UIImageView
Tableview subviews: UIImageView
Tableview subviews: UITextField
```

No sign of UITableViewCellReorderControl. what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Override `setEditing: animated:` method of `UITableviewCell`. So, when your `UITableView` get in editing mode, it will call this method.

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing: editing animated: YES];

    if (editing) {

       UIView* reorderControl = [cell huntedSubviewWithClassName:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"];
       NSLog(@"%@", reorderControl);
       [reorderControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }   
}
```

For more details, go through [UITableViewCell class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/)

Comment: I declared 

 `MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell*)[editTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];` but it gives error for **huntedSubviewWithClassName** like

`No visible @interface for 'MyTableCell' declares the selector huntedSubviewWithClassName:`