# How can I change the color of the reorder accessory in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

There's a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141947/how-to-make-reorder-control-of-uitableviewcell-in-left-side) on how to move the reorder accessory in a UITableViewCell.  I'd like to keep it where it is but change its color because the background color of my table isn't white.  It looks like I could follow the same basic approach shown below, but I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to change the color of this programmatically drawn control than just replacing it with a programmatically drawn control of my own?

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
            // the problem: change view color
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want it as mentioned in here:http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point/ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with Antonis's concerns about possible future changes to iOS, I ended up following the approach I describe in the question, simply redrawing the accessory in a different color over the system accessory.  The reason is that this view comes with the interaction for dragging the cell; if I tried to remove it and draw my own, I became unable to move the cell.  I extended the MSCellAccessory library.  Here's my willDisplayCell method:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* view in cell.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
            MSCellAccessory *overlayControl = [MSCellAccessory accessoryWithType:FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL color:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.353 green:0.153 blue:0.035 alpha:1.0]];
            [overlayControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)];
            [view addSubview:overlayControl];
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my extension to MSCellAccessory.m:

```
#define FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_START_X                        CGRectGetMinX(self.bounds)+15
#define FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_END_X                          CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds)-15
#define FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_1_Y                     19
#define FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_2_Y                     22.5
#define FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_3_Y                     26
#define FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_WIDTH                   2
```

and

```
} else if(_accType == FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL) {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_START_X, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_1_Y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_END_X, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_1_Y);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_START_X, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_2_Y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_END_X, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_2_Y);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_START_X, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_3_Y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_END_X, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_3_Y);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, FLAT_REORDER_CONTROL_STROKE_WIDTH);

[self.accessoryColor setStroke];

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off implementing the custom reorder accessory on your own, as a custom view that slides in when the `UITableView` enters editing mode.

The answer you mention navigates the internal `UITableViewCell` view hierarchy and makes assumptions about class names like `UITableViewCellReorderControl` which could change in future versions of iOS and break your code.