# How to change UITableViewCell indentation direction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`. When user touches on Reorder button, I change the `UITableView` isEditing property to `true`. This causes the cell's to indent from left to right, and the reorder control to show up:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to change the indention direction for it to happen from right to left? I have tried setting the indentationLevel of `UITableViewCell` to a negative number, but it has no effect:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    indentationLevel = -10
}
```

Or, another option would be to make the reorder control to appear on the left side of the cell.

Edit:

I was able to change the reorder button to the left side of my cell using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254401/2716479

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make reorder control of UITableViewCell in left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141947/how-to-make-reorder-control-of-uitableviewcell-in-left-side)

Comment: Put your cell’s content in the cell’s contentView and use the delegate method to indicate that your cells should not be indented on edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by defining `semanticContentAttribute` property. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254401/2716479